# MemoryCache expired items - null reference exception

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memorycache

We have a problem in our batch processing application. It is a console application written in C# that is running in a loop at takes tasks from database. It (almost) never quits - just for deployments. We use MemoryCache (hidden under our abstraction layer) to cache some data. Occasionally we get null reference exception with following stack trace:

```
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheEntry.Release(MemoryCache cache, CacheEntryRemovedReason reason)
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore.RemoveFromCache(MemoryCacheEntry entry, CacheEntryRemovedReason reason, Boolean delayRelease)
at System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCacheStore.Remove(MemoryCacheKey key, MemoryCacheEntry entryToRemove, CacheEntryRemovedReason reason)
at System.Runtime.Caching.ExpiresBucket.FlushExpiredItems(DateTime utcNow, Boolean useInsertBlock)
at System.Runtime.Caching.CacheExpires.FlushExpiredItems(Boolean checkDelta, Boolean useInsertBlock)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback()
at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire()
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I browsed through decompiled `MemoryCache`, `MemoryCacheEntry`, `MemoryCacheStore` and `ExpiresBucket` and (as far as I can tell) the process of items expiration and removal is quite a "defensing-programming" piece of software. I don't see any indication that what is actually stored in cache could influence this process.

I noticed that under the hood our cache abstraction layer is using multiple `MemoryCache` instances. I looked a bit, but only found that this can influence application performance (which isn't an issue for us now). But I started to think if there isn't some race condition that could cause those multiple `MemoryCache`s to cause this type of error. Like for example framework triggers clearing of expired items for all (or some) instances of `MemoryCache` and they're processed together and somehow `MemoryCacheStore` is handled in two different threads. Just a thought that I have, but maybe someone had a similar issue and could share what was the root cause.

We're using .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: We will need a [mcve].

Comment: The MemoryCache class is explicitly marked as threadsafe, so it should be safe. So I would expect it to be safe. But bugs may always exist. It might, as mjwills mentions, be worth setting up a small program that uses the cache in a similar way as in your product to help isolate the problem.

Comment: @JonasH, I'm in a process, but not expecting it to be easy. There're tones of layers and different packages using the cache. If I reproduce it I'll (probably) know that I have to redesign abstraction to have single instance of MemoryCache.

Comment: One idea could be to switch to the newer [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycache) implementation. It should be easier to migrate than isolate the bug of the old one (assuming that there is a bug).